# How to delete an object from array by reference (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Simple question, but I cannot find a solution.

I have an array of objects.
I also have a reference to an object from this array.

I want to delete the object from the array.

How to do it in Javascript (without comparing object properties)?

PS It is easy to do it in C# (using List collection)

```
 List<SomeObject> list = ........ ;
 SomeObject element =  ......... ;
 list.Remove(element);
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Both your examples are arrays of references to objects. In the first case the references are hidden, but they still exist. `var a = {}; var b = a;` is there a difference between a and b? Is a an object and b a reference to an object? A: No, they are both references to an object.

Comment: @Tibos you didn;t understand me. I thought he has `var g=[{a:1},{b:2}];var myObj={a:1}....and now he needs to find myObj`

Comment: @RoyiNamir I see. Well he did say "a reference to an object from this array". Anyway, glad to have cleared the misunderstanding :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexOf to get the index of the object and splice to remove it from the array:

```
var arr = [ { name: 0}, { name : 1 } , {name : 2 } ];
var myObj = arr[1];

arr.splice(arr.indexOf(myObj),1);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir this line `arr.splice(arr.indexOf(myObj),1);` does the same thing as `list.Remove(element);` just different syntax

Comment: Does indexOf compare objects by reference (just to double-check)?

Comment: @RoyiNamir The original code and the version i edited now are entirely equivalent. I did update it to be word-for-word identical to what the OP described. As for IE9+, indeed, but a shim for indexOf can be found in many places, including [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: @MaximEliseev it compares by strict equality which in case of objects means comparison by reference.

Comment: This question can not be answred. there are missing details.

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's still the same answer. Anyways you could wrap Tibos answer in your own implementation nicer syntax, but imo thats more hassel then just doing what he is doing...

Comment: You can extend Array.prototype to do this, so then for every array it would be possible to call something like array.remove(object). Since JS arrays are not the arrays in common meaning - they are rather another map of integers to objects - this is completely legal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with arrays directly. You will have to find or roll your own  implementation of an collection which supports similar operation.